# $\sin^2x/x^4$: investigate the convergence of the improper integral

Tags: integration

Investigate the convergence of the improper integral
$$
\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sin^2x}{x^4}\,dx
$$
Was ill, hard to understand

Comment: What bounds for the integral?

Comment: 0 +00 they are/

Comment: next time you make a question, try to show what you had tried, otherwise it is likely you dont get answers and the question could be closed fast

Answer (score 2):

Hint: consider separately
$$
\int_0^{1}\frac{\sin^2x}{x^4}\,dx
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
\int_1^{\infty}\frac{\sin^2x}{x^4}\,dx
$$
The latter converges because, for $x\ge1$,
$$
\frac{\sin^2x}{x^4}\le\frac{1}{x^4}
$$
The former can be written as
$$
\int_0^{1}\frac{\sin^2x}{x^2}\frac{1}{x^2}\,dx
$$
Can you go on?

Comment: Probably no.....

Comment: @SiberianPlayer: $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{x^2}$ is divergent, and so it is your integral.

Answer (score -1):

It's clearly divergent

$$ \lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+}\frac{sin^2(x)}{x^4} > \lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+}\frac{1}{x} =\infty $$